# Form data not inserted in database, because of wrong error handling

Tags: javascript, php, html, error-handling

I tried to implement form validation in my registration page. I have given each error a corresponding name e.g. `emailErr` `passErr` `repeatpassErr` The variables are an empty string by default, otherwise when i correctly submit the form the html code will return an error which says that there is an undefined variable. But the problem with defining the error names as empty strings, is that the information never gets into the database the way I did with  `if(!isset($emailErr, $passErr, $repeatpassErr))` because the variables are always set. I don't know if there is another way to display error messages, or if the if statement can be fixed in another way. I hope you can help me!

This is my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

//connect to the database
require 'opendb.php';

$emailErr = $passErr = $repeatpassErr = "";

//check if a variable is set, in this case the register button
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    //variable declaration
    $mail = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['mail'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordrepeat = $_POST['passwordrepeat'];
    $province = $_POST['province'];

    //check if email input isn't blank and if provided email is valid
    if (empty($mail)) {
        $emailErr = "Vul uw e-mailadres in";
    } elseif(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) and !empty($mail)) {
        $emailErr = "Vul een geldig e-mailadres in";
    } else {
        // prepare statement for checking whether an emailaddress is already taken
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT mail FROM users WHERE mail = :mail');
        //bind the user's mail and fetch the row of the emailaddress that is the same
        $stmt->execute(array(':mail' => $mail));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //check if a row with an equal emailaddress can be found
        if(!empty($row['mail'])){
            $emailErr = 'Dit e-mailadres is al in gebruik';
        }
    }

    //check if password inputs aren't blank and longer than 5 characters
    if (empty($password)) {
        $passErr = "Vul uw wachtwoord in";
    } elseif(strlen($password) < 5 and !empty($password)) {
        $passErr = "Wachtwoord is te kort";
    }
    if (empty($passwordrepeat)) {
        $repeatpassErr = "Vul uw herhaalde wachtwoord in";
    } elseif(strlen($passwordrepeat) < 5 and !empty($passwordrepeat)) {
        $repeatpassErr = "Herhaalde wachtwoord is te kort";
    }

    //check if the password is equal to the repeated password
    if($password != $passwordrepeat and !empty($password) and !empty($passwordrepeat)) {
        $passErr = 'Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen';
    }

    //if (empty($province)) $error[] = "Vul uw provincie in";


    //if no error is found, execute statement
    if(!isset($emailErr, $passErr, $repeatpassErr)) {
        //hash the password
        $hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        //prepare statement for the insertion of user's mail, password and province into table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (mail, password, province) VALUES (:mail, :password, :province)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        //bind the variables to the placeholder that is used to prepare the statement
        $stmt->bindValue(':mail', $mail);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $hashedpassword); 
        $stmt->bindValue(':province', $province);
        //execute the statement and insert account in database
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        //check if signup is succesful and create a session
        if($result){
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $mail;
            header('Location: views.php');
            exit;
        }  
    }
}
?>
```

This is my html code:

```
<body>      
    <div class="container">
        <div class="register">          
            <form method="post" action="userregistration.php">  
                <h1>Sign up</h1>
                <label for="email">E-mailadres:</label><br>
                <div class="infobox">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    <input class="text-input" type="email" name="mail" placeholder="example:emailname@mail.com"><br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br>
                </div>

                <label for="password">Wachtwoord:</label><span class="passrequirements"> (minimaal 5 karakters)</span><br>
                <div class="infobox">
                    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                    <input class="text-input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="******"><br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $passErr;?></span><br>
                </div>

                <label for="password">Herhaal wachtwoord:</label><br>
                <div class="infobox">
                    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                    <input class="text-input" type="password" name="passwordrepeat" id="password" placeholder="******"><br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $repeatpassErr;?></span><br>
                </div>

                <label for="country">Provincie:</label><br>
                <div class="infobox">
                    <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
                    <select name="province">
                        <option value="DR">Drenthe</option>
                        <option value="FL,">Flevoland</option>
                        <option value="FR">Friesland</option>
                        <option value="GE">Gelderland</option>
                        <option value="GR">Groningen</option>
                        <option value="LI">Limburg</option>
                        <option value="NB">Noord-Brabant</option>
                        <option value="NH">Noord-Holland</option>
                        <option value="OV">Overijssel</option>
                        <option value="UT">Utrecht</option>
                        <option value="ZE">Zeeland</option>
                        <option value="ZH">Zuid-Holland</option>
                    </select><br>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="signup-button" name="register">Registreer</button><br>
                <a class="login-link" href="userlogin.php">Ik heb al een account</a>
            </form>         
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: why are not you checking isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] and $_POST['repeatPassword'] ) ?

Comment: You're checking the variables aren't set `!isset($emailErr, $passErr, $repeatpassErr)` ... yet you set them at the top of the script? `$emailErr = $passErr = $repeatpassErr = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using isset() to check if there are errors, you could use empty():

```
if(empty($emailErr) && empty($passErr) && empty($repeatpassErr)) {
```

this way if the error vars are empty strings it will go through but not if any of the vars has a value thats not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

the `if` condition probably should look alike that, because `isset()` will always return true, when a variable had been initialized to empty string ...one can check either with [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
!empty($emailErr) && !empty($passErr) && !empty($repeatpassErr)
```

or with [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
strlen($emailErr) == 0 && strlen($passErr) == 0 && strlen($repeatpassErr) == 0
```

while checking the `$_POST` fields with `isset()` and then escaping any input is suggested; because beside the basic string validation, there is no input sanitation in place, at all.

in general, having an array `$errors`, into which one can push error messages is rather flexible, while one can then check for errors alike: `if(sizeof($errors) == 0) {}`.

Comment: Usage of isset, from the same link you referenced:

bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )

Comment: @LucasBorges yes it accepts multiple parameters, but another quote of the link: `If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set.` this means that when you negate it with `!` the logic does not apply as OP wants.

Comment: "*while I've not even completed writing the answer.*" ... Dont be so quick to answer that you post an incomplete thought ?

Comment: some people probably have nothing better to do that to wait for answers to down-vote... and I just would have needed one more +1 for PHP badge, which sucks.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes  i still need to prevent sql injections btw :). I dont get why people instantly downvote while its a good asnwer though -- unfortunately i cant upvote yet :/

Comment: @Cashbee No. `!isset($x, $y, $x)` is the same as `!isset($x) && !isset($y) && !isset($z)`

Comment: @LucasBorges actually, no it isn't! let's assume `$x = 'a'; $y = ''; $z = '';` then `isset($x,$y,$z)` is false. therefore `!isset($x,$y,$z)` is true. but `!isset($x) && !isset($y) && !isset($z)` is false.

Comment: oh and @MartinZeitler if you look at the original code again you will see that your negations `!` on empty() are not correct. OP wants to go into the if-block when the vars *are* empty. ;) - I agree on the `$errors` array though, it is a nicer way of handling it.